# Collect file descriptors in ECS tasks to send to Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm currently running into a problem with our application where the we have too many files opened and it's causing a errors. I've increased the ulimit for NOFILE in the task definition and I'm making code changes but I need to be able to monitor the open files for individual containers to make sure the code changes are working.

Is there way to simply configure the cloudwatch-agent or the like to send the metrics to cloudwatch?

The only other idea I got is to create a bash script that logs into individual containers to collect the data and send up to cloudwatch.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I wrote a quick medium post detailing what I did
https://medium.com/@the-poole/aws-ecs-instances-file-descriptors-monitoring-8392a73f9b43